# Setting up two different static directories (angular apps (dist) in node.js Express framework? is not working?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have two angular apps and single node app both angular apps consuming api's from node app. I want to setting up these two clients apps from nodeJs. i wrote the following code but its not working as expected?

I tried this first.

```
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + '/admin-dist'));
app.use("/customer", express.static(__dirname + '/customer-dist'));
```

but  did'nt work from me then I tried this.

then I tried this.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/admin-dist'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/customer-dist'));

app.all('/customer', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/customer-dist/index.html');
});

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/admin-dist/index.html');
});
```

If I am doing something wrong? let me know. Thanks!

Comment: To help with `express.static()` questions, you have to tell us these things for a particular request that isn't work: 1) What URL is the browser sending to your server, 2) Where in your file system is the file that you want `express.static()` to send for that URL?  As your question stands now, there's not enough info in the question to know what you want to do or what the problem is.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to ''domain/" then i want to return admin dist.....if "domain/customer" then i want to send customer-dist folder....

Comment: I can help you in minutes if you answer my two questions.  Pick one full URL that you want to work, tell me what the URL is and then tell me exactly in your file system where the file is that you want served for that URL. Please read my question and answer those two points.  I can help you minutes if you answer those. If not, I will just go help others instead. Your answer to my questions should be something like this: URL is `/xyz` and the file is `__dirname + "/admin-dist/xyz"`. Or, perhaps URL is `/admin/xyz` and the file is `__dirname + "/admin-dist/xyz"`.  I need to know those TWO things.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok Thanks ..... URL is `/customer` and the file is `__dirname + "/customer-dist/index.html` OR URL is `/` and the file is `__dirname + "/admin-dist/index.html` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> URL is /customer and the file is __dirname + "/customer-dist/index.html OR URL is / and the file is __dirname + "/admin-dist/index.html

For that first situation, you would use this:

```
app.use("/customer", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "customer-dist")));
```

With that statement, you will get the following:

```
 /customer                 =>   __dirname/customer-dist/index.html
 /customer/foo.html        =>   __dirname/customer-dist/foo.html
 /customer/admin/test.html =>   __dirname/customer-dist/admin/test.html
```

For the second, you would use this:

```
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "admin-dist")));
```

And, that will match up these requests with these files:

```
 /                  =>   __dirname/admin-dist/index.html
 /foo.html          =>   __dirname/admin-dist/foo.html
 /admin/test.html   =>   __dirname/admin-dist/admin/test.html
```

**You should make sure the two statements are in the order shown here** so the more specific statement `/customer` one is first and the less specific one doesn't have any chance of stealing requests from the more specific one.

If these aren't working for you, then something else about your configuration or your problem statement is wrong.

Comment: I am working with my application i updated all my `/customer` app (which is angular (dist) file). It gives me an error: 'used to apply style from 'url' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. Angular'.....If you have any idea please let me know...

Comment: @user10759242 - I'd suggest you write a new question on this topic.  You will need to know exactly which request from the page is causing this, what the `<style>` tag is that leads to it, what the desired target file is that is supposed to be served for that (full path to that file) and which route in your server is supposed to be serving that file and which file the server is actually trying to send.

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS the order of youe middleware matters.  Route `/` will match both `/` && `/customers` hence why they're going to the same application.  Switching the order should correct the issue.

```
app.use("/customer", express.static(__dirname + '/customer-dist'));
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + '/admin-dist'));
```